# How do I downsample a video's framerate with ffmpeg, adding motion blur in the process?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video file with 960 frames per second and I'd like to downsample it to 30 frames per second, blending every 32 source frames into one new frame.

All I could find were people suggesting ffmpeg's tblend and framestep filters, but at this scale, chaining these filters together gets old really fast. Are there any alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: You  don't have to process all 32 frames. You can select 4 or 8 and then apply the tb/fs chain.

Comment: If I don‘t process all 32 frames, the motion blur will look bad. So I kinda have to do this.

Comment: You are consolidating images across a 33 millisecond interval; I doubt there would be any significant difference.

Comment: Just as there is a noticeable difference between 30 and 60 FPS, there's a noticeable difference between using 8 and 32 frames for motion blur. I need a solution, not some hacky workaround that involves discarding 75% of the material I can work with.

Comment: You can try the framerate filter: `-vf framerate=30`.

Comment: That filter sadly doesn't seem to interpolate frames when sampling down.

Comment: Then you're stuck with my original method. Someone's submitted a new filter patch that automates it, but it's still in review.